# Should a broken socket be closed?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am reading out of a TCP-socket:

```
int read_result = recv(socket_fd, &some_struct, some_size, 0);
```

If `read_result` would be equal to `-1`, should I still call `close` on that file descriptor or just leave it?

Comment: It depends on the context. If the `recv` is inside a loop, you may wish to continue the loop on some errors (e.g. `EINTR`). Otherwise, the general rule is to handle the error (e.g. `perror`) and then do a `close`. Otherwise, the socket descriptor is left hanging (i.e. you might use up all the descriptors if you did a retry by doing another `socket` call)

Comment: The only time there's not much point in trying to close the socket is if `errno` equals `EBADF` (bad file descriptor).  That means that `socket_fd` doesn't refer to a valid file descriptor, so there's no point in trying to close it.  For any other error, you could close the socket if that's appropriate to the application.  However, you shouldn't close the socket simply because you received an error; many errors are transient (`EBADF` is unlikely to be transient, unless another thread opens a file and is coincidentally assigned the same file descriptor as `socket_fd`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `recv` man page there are a host of reasons for which `recv` might return `-1`(EAGAIN, EBADF, EINVAL, ENOMEM etc). I would suggest checking `errno` against these expected return values and modifying your code to act accordingly. If you are writing a library, you might want to return an library specific error code. If you are application, you might want to perhaps die or return an error code to the caller. It would depend on the context.

The first step to solving this however, would be to understand the various error codes that can be returned and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Generally, *any* resource acquired should be released before exiting the application. That includes "bad" handles (which might still have other resources attached to them, like memory). While many modern OS do this kind of cleanup for you when a process exits, some don't, and unreleased resources are a programming error.

Comment: I want to second @learnlearnlearn's comment that to write a robust socket implementation, you need to understand the error cases, because some of them require specific handling (e.g., EAGAIN) that you have to design for.  Particularly if you plan to put TLS on top at some point; the last thing you want to do on your server is trigger unnecessary public-key operations, by dropping a socket that only had a temporary issue.